# PHP: foreach applying an increase of one number to every loop

Tags: php, loops, foreach, laravel-5, sequential

I have this:

```
foreach ($itemsCart as $value) {

            $items['itemId' . $value->id]               = $value->id;
            $items['itemDescription' . $value->id]      = $value->name;
            $items['itemAmount' . $value->id]           = $value->price;
            $items['itemQuantity' . $value->id]         = $value->quantity;
        }
```

This output:

```
[itemId9] => 9
[itemDescription9] => Product
[itemAmount9] => 5.00
[itemQuantity9] => 1

[itemId5] => 5
[itemDescription5] => Other Product
[itemAmount5] => 8.00
[itemQuantity5] => 2
```

**I need a sequential number in key of array, but in every loop:**

```
[itemId1] => 9
[itemDescription1] => Product
[itemAmount1] => 5.00
[itemQuantity1] => 1

[itemId2] => 5
[itemDescription2] => Other Product
[itemAmount2] => 8.00
[itemQuantity2] => 2
```

Sequential number (started from 1) every loop of the foreach...

If I set i++, i get:

```
[itemId1] => 9
[itemDescription2] => Product
[itemAmount3] => 5.00
[itemQuantity4] => 1

[itemId5] => 5
[itemDescription6] => Other Product
[itemAmount7] => 8.00
[itemQuantity8] => 2
```

what can I do? I have lost many hours trying to solve this.. :(

Thanks

Comment: If you're reading from an array shouldn't the array have the unique product id's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by *If I set i++, i get...* ?

Because something like that should work :

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($itemsCart as $value) {
    $i++;
    $items['itemId' . $i]           = $value->id;
    $items['itemDescription' . $i]  = $value->name;
    $items['itemAmount' . $i]       = $value->price;
    $items['itemQuantity' . $i]     = $value->quantity;
}
```

Something simpler, if your `$itemCart` keys are integers 0, 1, ... :

```
foreach ($itemCart as $key => $value)
{
    $items['itemId' . $key] = $value->id;
    $items['itemDescription' . $key]  = $value->name;
    $items['itemAmount' . $key]       = $value->price;
    $items['itemQuantity' . $key]     = $value->quantity;
}
```

Comment: Btw, I don't really like the idea of writing indices like that. A bidimensionnal array, like Mark Baker said, could be nicer.

Answer (score 1):

A basic nested array might be more appropriate than what you're trying to do:

```
foreach ($itemsCart as $value) {
    $items[$value->id]['itemId']               = $value->id;
    $items[$value->id]['itemDescription']      = $value->name;
    $items[$value->id]['itemAmount']           = $value->price;
    $items[$value->id]['itemQuantity']         = $value->quantity;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using $item->ID, use the $i that you said you have.

```
$i=1;
foreach ($itemsCart as $value) {
    $items['itemId' . $i]               = $value->id;
    $items['itemDescription' . $i]      = $value->name;
    $items['itemAmount' . $i]           = $value->price;
    $items['itemQuantity' . $i++]         = $value->quantity;
}
```

The ++ increments the $i after it is concatenated to the string. You can omit that and use $i++ between each line of code.

Answer (score 0):

Just use another variable as a counter:

```
$id = 1;
foreach ($itemsCart as $value) {
     $items['itemId' . $id]               = $value->id;
     $items['itemDescription' . $id]      = $value->name;
     $items['itemAmount' . $id]           = $value->price;
     $items['itemQuantity' . $id]         = $value->quantity;
     $id += 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! That works fine too!!!!! 3 different ways worked as I needed. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

```
$i = 1;
foreach ($itemsCart as $value) {
   $items['itemId' . $i]           = $value->id;
   $items['itemDescription' . $i]  = $value->name;
   $items['itemAmount' . $i]       = $value->price;
   $items['itemQuantity' . $i]     = $value->quantity;
   $i++;
}
```